# android sqlite - same value - different language

Tags: android, sqlite, localization

I would like to get from sqlite value that will be different for OS language (localization). How to do this?

Creating table like this:

```
create table test (
_id integer primary key autoincrement,
some_value text,
some_value_en text
);
```

and get appropriate value (some_value or some_value_en) would be a good solution?

Comment: What are those text values used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need that for, but you can use Android's localization infrastructure to get the column name. Put "some_value" in a String resource in values\strings.xml, and override it in values-en\strings.xml with "some_value_en" .

SELECT according to the column name.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you want to dinamically access localized resources. What you can doo is first get the Identifier with this method:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("name_of_resource", "id", getPackageName());
```

Name of resource could be whatever you get from the database. The localized string.xml will do the rest. So basically you just store the default tag in the database.

```
String localizedResource = getResources().getString(id);
```

Keep in mind its much more effective to access the resources by Id directly.